# Query not sending correctly to move img file into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, image

I am creating an admin page on my site to create new products. I created this with data like a productid, name, img etc. The issue I'm having has to do with the img file not being moved to my database with the correct file. I'm sending a file to my database rather than storing the entire img, but the file is not moving correctly from my productpics file to my database. However, the image is being successfully stored in the productpics file. All of the other data is successfully being inserted into my database.

I have a default img in my productpics file to set as a default img, but it basically a place holder in the img container until a picture is uploaded.

In the following query my img row in my db table is 'img' and the variable name in this query is $file.

```
$file =  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']

['tmp_name'],"productpics/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
            //Connection
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
            $q = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO products (product_id, name, price, saleprice, final_price, shippingprice, category, item_details, item_details2, description, viewproduct_type, date_created, img) VALUES ('$product_id', '$name', '$price', '$saleprice', '$final_price', '$shippingprice', '$category', '$item_details', '$item_details2', '$description', '$viewproduct_type', '$date', '$file')")
                            or die("Could not INSERT: " . mysqli_error($con)); 
                         "Your product was successfully added."; 
            }Session::flash('addproduct', 'Your product was successfully added.');
        }   else {
                foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                }
            }
    } 
}
?>
```

I then tried doing this two ways from what I've seen. With INSERT and UPDATE. Which would be the best for my scenario?

This is the INSERT way. The result in my database is a "1" that posted into it. The file name I was trying to enter was chest.jpg

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['create'])){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']

['tmp_name'],"productpics/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
                $q = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT products img='$_FILES[file][name]' WHERE product_id=$product_id");

        }
?>
```

Then I tried UPDATE. The result entry in my database was product[array]

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['create'])){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']

['tmp_name'],"productpics/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
                $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE products SET img='$_FILES[file][name]' WHERE product_id=$product_id");

        }
?>
```

This is my form. (condensed)

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div class="field">
                                    <label for="product_id">Product ID</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="product_id" class="smallinputbar" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label for="name">Product Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label for="price">Product Price</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="price" required>
                                </div>

                                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                                    <label for="button">
                                        <input type="submit" id="button" name="create" value="Create New Product">
                                    </label>

                            <span class="floatright">
                                        <input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile">
                                        <input type="submit" name="create" id="signinButton" value="Upload">
                                    </span>


                </form>
```

Does anyone know what is going on with my query that is preventing this from working?

Comment: `{$_FILES[file][name]}`, but even then, a bad idea.  Use prepared statements.

Comment: Which would be the better approach INSERT or UPDATE?

Comment: The beauty of mysqli is that it supports prepared statements.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure how to make this a prepared statement. I've only used this method. How would it be atructured?

Comment: Adding in the   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"productpics/". {$_FILES['file']['name']});   did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Semi-advanced PHP strings 101: You cannot directly use multi-dimensional arrays in `"`-quoted strings:

```
$arr['a']['b'] = 'c';
echo "$arr[a][b]";
```

will output `Array[b]`, rather than the exected `c`. PHP's parser is not greedy, and stops arrays after the first `[]` brace pair. You need to use the extended `{}` notation:

```
echo "{$arr['a']['b']}";
```

which WILL echo out `c`.

And note that your code is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), as well as not checking if your move call succeeded or not. Never ever assume that operations on 'external' resources succeeded. Always assume failure, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Which would be the better approach INSERT or UPDATE?

Comment: my usual M.O. is start a transaction, insert a skeleton record, do any external stuff (e.g. move files around), then update/commit as needed. That way if any of the external stuff fails, you just rollback and everything's undone.

Comment: So, since I am using INSERT in the first part of code I posted, should the second part I posted associated with the image be UPDATE? I have it updating the set image.

Comment: Adding in the     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"productpics/". {$_FILES['file']['name']});  did not work, unfortunately.